# How to vertically align a p child of a parent div, with intention to easily text-align the child?

Tags: css

My goal is to vertically align a child p of a parent div. Currently, I use Flexbox. But it prevents me to modify the text-align.

My expected result: The text is vertically aligned, and can be text-aligned.

My actual result: The text is vertically aligned but it can't be text-aligned.

```css
body {
 background-color: silver; 
}
div {
  background-color: white;
}
header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="flex: 1;">
      <section>
        <p class="text-center">Section</p>
      </section>
      <article>
        <p class="text-center">Article</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <aside class="center" style="flex: 1;">
      <p style="text-align: right;">Aside</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
```

[image: aside]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? (sorry had to change up the classes a bit). What I did was added a display:grid; and align-items:center; on all parents of the p tags.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex">
        <div class="flex-item">
            <section>
                <p class="text-center">Section</p>
            </section>
            <article>
                <p class="text-center">Article</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <aside class="center flex-item">
            <p>Aside</p>
        </aside>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  body {
   background-color: silver; 
  }
  div {
   background-color: white;
  }
  header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {
   background-color: white;
   padding: 10px;
   border: solid;
  }
 .flex {
   display: flex;
 }
 .flex-item {
   flex: 1;
 }
 .flex-item section,
 .flex-item article,
 .center {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .flex-item section,
 .flex-item article {
   height: 200px; /* this is just to see the vertical layout */
 }
```

You should now be able to freely align, left, center and right, but there are more ways to do this. If you're worried about using grid, it has good support and it works fine on most major browsers :)

Comment: Your solution use `display: grid`, I tested it works and it is mobile friendy.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer every, I hope this helps!

This happens because you put `flex: 1;` on the parent of the "aside" text, changing the size of the parent but not the child. Try changing `flex: initial;` on the "aside" text parent and you'll see what I mean. You can fix this in a ton of ways, one way is to put `width: 100%;` on the "aside" text `<p></p>`

Answer (score 0):

you can put either `p {flex-grow: 1}` or `p {min-width: 100%}`